# What's the scam?

Tags: scams, paypal

Two strangers have sent us money to our paypal account in the past week; the total is almost $700. What kind of a scam is this? I've had no contact with either of these people; the money just appeared as a payment received. I haven't had good customer service from paypal in the past, so I'm thinking if I call them, I'll end up with no help, and wasting an hour or two of my life trying to talk to people who won't and can't do anything. Have you heard of anything like this?

Comment: I'm going to guess that you'll shortly be receiving a message along the lines of "Oops sorry I paypal'ed the wrong person. Would be you so kind as to withdraw the money and send it by (insert some irrevocable method here) onward to (some other person)?", followed shortly by the transaction being reversed by Paypal - and you're out $700.

Comment: The fact that this is paypal makes it a bit different, but the core of the likely method of scamming remains the same as in the noted duplicate.

Comment: It's not your money, as far as anyone knows you don't know it's in there. Just act as if you haven't seen it and see what happens to it. Don't wait a second worrying about it.

Comment: Typically the money has been sent from a hacked account. In a few days you'll get a message asking you to pass the money back to a different account, obfuscating the origin and making you into a money-mule. The more steps between the original hacked account and the end-user, the less likely that the police will expend the time required to track and capture the culprit